# Why are these elements not the same width?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Google Chrome (tested with version 50) if I set the width of a `<input>` element and a `<textarea>` element both to 500px, they are clearly not the same width. I tried explicitly removing any padding and they are still clearly not the same width. This does not happen in Mozilla Firefox. [See here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59tkctya/).

```
<input type="text"/>
<br/>
<textarea></textarea>

input, textarea {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The native padding for text input elements differ.

Add this in your **CSS**:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: `box-sizing` has been broadly supported for years. Don't think you need prefixes anymore: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: I didn't know this site but it's really very useful. Thank you !

Comment: Do you know why this happened? default box-sizing of both of them is content-box, then I think there should be a different in input's border or maybe textarea padding or ....

Comment: @Kermani: In Chrome, `input` has 2px border on all sides, 1px top + bottom padding and no padding on left + right whereas `textarea` has 1px border + 2px padding on all sides. In short `input` has 2px outside content box area on left and right whereas `textarea` has 3px. So there is a difference of 2px.

Comment: @Harry I will add your comment to my answer, that is so useful! thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is from `box-sizing` and you can add `box-sizing: border-box;` to them and they will have the same width.

> The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing
>   properties (width and height) should include. *(The CSS3 box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.)* [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

---

### Update:

And [@Herry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) described in a comment:

> In Chrome, input has 2px border on all sides, 1px top + bottom padding
>   and no padding on left + right whereas textarea has 1px border + 2px
>   padding on all sides. In short input has 2px outside content box area
>   on left and right whereas textarea has 3px. So there is a difference
>   of 2px.

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kermani/59tkctya/3/)